Azure batch translator status NotStarted after long
I am using the azure translation service to translate documents.
I try each 5s calling the operation-location and if more than 500 retries I throw an error. So approx after 42 min I still receive the status NotStarted from the operation-location. I do not understand how it can take so long, is there any way to estimate the max retry times ?
